# Issue with DataSourceHealthIndicator in Spring Boot actuator

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Looking at the source code for `DataSourceHealthIndicator` if it fails to figure out database it will use default query "SELECT 1;" to health status of the datasource.

This query fails in my environment. How can I configure `HealthCheckEndpoint` to use `DatasourceHealthIndicator` with custom query.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can define your own `HealthIndicator` with name `dbHealthIndicator` and it will be used instead of the default, something like

```
@Bean
public HealthIndicator dbHealthIndicator() {
    DataSourceHealthIndicator indicator = new DataSourceHealthIndicator(dataSource());
    indicator.setQuery("Your Query Here");
    return indicator;
}
```

Note that you may want [to share](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues) the database type and versions that you are using and which query fit so that this can be supported out-of-the-box. Boot already does for HSQL, Derby and Oracle plus all databases that support "SELECT 1"

Comment: Wouldn't it be a nice addition if the `spring.datasource.validation-query` would also be used (when set) for the `DataSourceHealthIndicator`?

Comment: Awesome yes. Can you create an issue with that suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: Whilst you where typing this comment I created [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1282) issue :).

Comment: In one go (at least in Spring Boot 2.1.1): `return new DataSourceHealthIndicator(dataSource(), "SELECT 1 FROM dual");`.

Answer (score 2):

There is an option to configure it without any java code.

`DataSourceHealthContributorAutoConfiguration` takes the validation query from `DataSourcePoolMetadata`.

E.g. for hikari, specify property `spring.datasource.hikari.connection-test-query=select 1`