# Disable and Replace Default DataSourceHealthIndicator

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, health-monitoring, spring-boot-actuator

I am currently working with a health monitoring framework implemented using the Spring Boot Actuator "health" endpoint. The Actuator infrastructure supports the creation of custom health checks and also provides a number of built-in health checks; one of these is `DataSourceHealthIndicator`.

[`DataSourceHealthIndicator`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.4.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/health/DataSourceHealthIndicator.java) is part of the [`org.springframework.boot.actuate.health`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/health) package, and is currently being used by our health framework to check the health of data sources. I have a need to use my own, slightly modified version of `DataSourceHealthIndicator` and to disable the "default."

I have tried the solutions suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24873283/issue-with-datasourcehealthindicator-in-spring-boot-actuator) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29865940/spring-boot-actuator-health-indicator), with no luck. What could I be doing wrong?

Thanks!

---

**Edit: 8/18/2016, 3:38 PM EST**

I've renamed my bean to `dbHealthIndicator` and added the following to my configuration class:

```
@Bean
public HealthIndicator dbHealthIndicator() {
     return new dbHealthIndicator();
}
```

I am now getting the following exceptions:

`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataAccessMapperFactory' defined in class path resource [udtContext.xml]`

`java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: Unable to start the Universal Connection Pool: oracle.ucp.UniversalConnectionPoolException`

---

**Edit: 8/19/2016, 9:22 AM EST**

This may help to demonstrate what I am trying to do. Currently, my `/health` endpoint returns something that looks like this:

```
dataSource: {
     status: "UP",
     database: "mySql",
     hello: "hello"
}
```

I would like for it to return something more like this, where the integer beside "result" is a status code returned by a stored procedure in my database:

```
dataSource: {
     status: "UP",
     database: "mySql",
     hello: "hello",
     result: 0
}
```

This is the method in `DataSourceHealthIndicator.java` that performs the check:

```
private void doDataSourceHealthCheck(Health.Builder builder) throws Exception {
    String product = getProduct();
    builder.up().withDetail("database", product);
    String validationQuery = getValidationQuery(product);
    if (StringUtils.hasText(validationQuery)) {
        try {
            // Avoid calling getObject as it breaks MySQL on Java 7
            List<Object> results = this.jdbcTemplate.query(validationQuery,
                    new SingleColumnRowMapper());
            Object result = DataAccessUtils.requiredSingleResult(results);
            builder.withDetail("hello", result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            builder.down(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

I need to add eight lines of code to this method, under `builder.withDetail("hello", result);`, to perform the call to the stored proc. I do not want to "decompile" the default class, and I am unable to override this method because it is private. I was thinking I could copy the `DataSourceHealthIndicator.java` code in my own bean, add my code, and rewire Spring to use this version instead, but I don't know if this is possible.

Comment: Why do you need your own `HealthIndicator` what is it you are trying to do that doesn't work/function in the original one?

Comment: M. Deinum, I'm hoping to override or extend the doDataSourceHealthCheck() method in the built-in DataSourceHealthIndicator to call a stored procedure in my database; however, Java does not support the overriding or extending of a private method. So, what I've done is copy DataSourceHealthIndicator and add about eight lines of code in my own custom bean. I want to use this "extended" version instead of the default. Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: But do you really want to disable the default one, or is this additional info? Yours won't work and I expect that you are trying to use autowiring in your own implementation, which isn't going to work. Take a look at the orginal health indicator (that gets a `DataSource` passed in as it should by the constructor). you should construct this as well. However I doubt you want to replace the existing one with yours, I guess you want both...

Comment: M. Deinum, thank you for your help! I've edited my original post to include more information about what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I still don't see why the proposed solutions wouldn't work. Those also clearly state that you need to inject a datasource. You aren't injecting anything into your health indicator. So I suspec tyou are using autowiring instead, which fails because that happens very early in the process.

Comment: M. Deinum, the issue is that I have a number of different data sources (`status`, `database`, and `hello` are returned for each of them). This is code that I am simply maintaining -- I am not the author -- and I do not fully understand the process by which the health framework connects to the data sources (I see no other `DataSource` injections; I suspect that there is a data source configuration file). I was really hoping that there would be a simple way to extend this class or "rewire" Spring to follow whatever process it is using with `DataSourceHealthIndicator` but with my version instead.

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, look at the source code of the configuration. If you really want to, then you need to disable the default and totally wire your own, probably by duplicating the configuration as well as part of the class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Normally I look at the configuration for that `HealthIndicator`. In this case it is the [`HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.DataSourcesHealthIndicatorConfiguration`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.DataSourcesHealthIndicatorConfiguration.html). As the first linked suggestion stated. You need to name your custom bean `dbHealthIndicator` so that the `@ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = "dbHealthIndicator")` doesn't allow the default to be registered.

Providing some startup logs or details of what isn't working for you would help people troubleshoot.

Here is an example of how I got it to work:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class StackoverflowWebmvcSandboxApplication {
    @Bean
    public HealthIndicator dbHealthIndicator() {
        return new HealthIndicator() {

            @Override
            public Health health() {
                return Health.status(Status.UP).withDetail("hello", "hi").build();
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(StackoverflowWebmvcSandboxApplication.class, args);
    }

    @RestController
    public class HelloController {
        @GetMapping("/hello")
        public String hello() {
            return "hello";
        }
    }
}
```

The `/health` endpoint then returned:

```
{
    "status": "UP",
    "db": {
        "status": "UP",
        "hello": "hi"
    },
    "diskSpace": {
        "status": "UP",
        "total": 127927316480,
        "free": 17191956480,
        "threshold": 10485760
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, Shawn! To give a little more detail, even when I rename my custom bean to dbHealthIndicator, the framework still seems to use the default (no error messages are returned). Is there any additional configuration or "rewiring" that needs to be done in order for it to register my health check instead?

Comment: Shawn, I've edited my original post to include my bean configuration code, as well as the exceptions I am now getting.

Comment: Do the startup logs show that bean being instantiated for use in the context?

Comment: I'm currently looking through the logs -- in the meantime, is there any additional configuration beyond renaming the bean and adding the above code that I need to do? (I think my inexperience with Spring is starting to show!)

Comment: I am going to try myself when I get home but based on what I am reading in the docs and the code it looks like your way should work

Comment: Updated my answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

An important point that didn't mentioned is without having the `validationTimeout` and `connectionTimeout` properties set in datasource config we will encounter infinite loop on `DataSourceHealthIndicator` and [health](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.x/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-health) check system becomes fully none-functional regardless of it implementation.

With respect the case in hand to provide this the candidate implementation will be look like this.

```html
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomHealth implements HealthIndicator {

    @Override
    public Health health() {
        ...
        return Health.status(healthIndicator.health().getStatus()).build();
    }

    private final DataSourceHealthIndicator healthIndicator;
}
```

```html
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        ...
        config.setInitializationFailTimeout(1000);
        config.setConnectionTimeout(1500);
        config.setValidationTimeout(1500);
        
        ...
```

```html
    @Bean
    public DataSourceHealthIndicator dataSourceHealthIndicator(){
        return new DataSourceHealthIndicator(dataSource, "SELECT 1");
    }
```

Please also note that you can simply turn off default HealthIndicators provided by actuator in your property files.

```html
YML

management:
  health:
    db:
      enabled: false
      
Properties

management.health.db.enabled: false
```